# How to receive string result from Delphi DLL in C++Builder?

Tags: c++, dll, return, builder

Calling a function from a DLL returning a `string` gives a memory error. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Following codes show me the first character of the returned string and then gives a memory error.

I am using Delphi 11.2 and C++Builder 5.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    HINSTANCE MyDll;

    typedef AnsiString(__stdcall *pfRes)(int);
    pfRes TestFunction;

    if ((MyDll = LoadLibrary("D:\\MyFirstLibrary.dll")) == NULL){
        ShowMessage("Cannot Load DLL !");
        return;
    }

    if ((TestFunction = (pfRes)GetProcAddress(MyDll,"TestFunction")) == NULL ) {
       ShowMessage("Cannot find DLL function!");
       return;
    }

    ShowMessage(TestFunction(24));
    FreeLibrary(MyDll);
}
```

DLL Code: (Delphi)(It works fine if call the dll from a delphi application)

```pascal
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.JSON;

{$R *.res}

function TestFunction(const _a: integer) : String; stdcall;
var
  StrJSon      : string;
begin
  StrJSon := 'TEST STRING'

  Result := StrJSon;
end;

exports
  TestFunction;
begin

end.
```

Comment: Given that you are asking about the behavior of `TestFunction`, may we see that code?

Comment: I have edited the question as dll code is in delphi and it works fine when I call the TestFunction from another delphi application.

Comment: Not an expert on Delphi but it might be something with the string type. 
First of all - try to see if the export is actually there. Use a tool like ``dumpbin`` or any other header reader. 
Secondly,  Try to split the function ``   ShowMessage(TestFunction(24));`` to 2 lines and see what ``TestFunction`` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi's `String` type is an alias for `AnsiString` in Delphi 2007 and earlier, but is an alias for `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009 and later.  Since you are using Delphi 11.2, `string` is going to alias `UnicodeString`, not `AnsiString`.  So, you have a type mismatch between your C++ and Delphi codes.

However, *neither* type is safe to pass over a DLL boundary, *unless* you compile both the DLL and EXE projects with Runtime Packages enabled. In which case, you should also change the DLL project to be a Package instead, and then have the EXE load it using `LoadPackage()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`.

Unfortunately, that approach is not going to work in your situation, since you are using C++Builder 5 instead of C++Builder 11.2, to match your Delphi 11.2.  Runtime Packages simply do not work across major version boundaries.

In which case, you will have to redesign your code to pass around a raw `char*` or `wchar_t*` pointer instead.  Either:

- make the DLL dynamically allocate a C-style null-terminated string and return its pointer to the EXE, and then have the EXE pass that pointer back into the DLL to free the memory, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    HINSTANCE MyDll;

    typedef char* (__stdcall *pfRes)(int);
    typedef void (__stdcall *pfFree)(char*);

    pfRes TestFunction;
    pfFree FreeFunction;

    if ((MyDll = LoadLibrary("D:\\MyFirstLibrary.dll")) == NULL){
        ShowMessage("Cannot Load DLL !");
        return;
    }

    TestFunction = (pfRes) GetProcAddress(MyDll, "TestFunction");
    FreeFunction = (pfFree) GetProcAddress(MyDll,"FreeFunction");

    if (TestFunction == NULL || FreeFunction == NULL) {
       ShowMessage("Cannot find DLL function!");
       FreeLibrary(MyDll);
       return;
    }

    char *ptr = TestFunction(24);
    ShowMessage(ptr);
    FreeFunction(ptr);

    FreeLibrary(MyDll);
}
```

```pascal
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.JSON;

{$R *.res}

function TestFunction(const _a: integer) : PAnsiChar; stdcall;
var
  StrJSon : string;
begin
  StrJSon := 'TEST STRING'
  Result := StrNew(PAnsiChar(UTF8String(StrJSon)));
end;

procedure FreeFunction(_a: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  StrDispose(_a);
end;

exports
  TestFunction,
  FreeFunction;

begin
end.
```

- have the EXE pre-allocate a `char[]` or `wchar_t[]` buffer of sufficient size and pass a pointer to it into the DLL, which can then simply fill the buffer as needed, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    HINSTANCE MyDll;

    typedef int (__stdcall *pfRes)(int, char*, int);
    pfRes TestFunction;

    if ((MyDll = LoadLibrary("D:\\MyFirstLibrary.dll")) == NULL){
        ShowMessage("Cannot Load DLL !");
        return;
    }

    TestFunction = (pfRes) GetProcAddress(MyDll, "TestFunction");
    if (TestFunction == NULL) {
       ShowMessage("Cannot find DLL function!");
       FreeLibrary(MyDll);
       return;
    }

    char buf[256];
    if (TestFunction(24, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)
        ShowMessage(buf);

    /* or:
    int len = TestFunction(24, NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        char *buf = new char[len];
        if (TestFunction(24, buf, len) > 0)
            ShowMessage(buf);
        delete[] buf;
    }
    */

    FreeLibrary(MyDll);
}
```

```pascal
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.JSON;

{$R *.res}

function TestFunction(const _a: integer; _buf: PAnsiChar; _size: Integer) : Integer; stdcall;
var
  StrJSon : string;
  StrUtf8 : UTF8String;
  iSize : Integer;
begin
  StrJSon := 'TEST STRING'
  StrUtf8 := UTF8String(StrJSon);
  iSize := Length(StrUtf8) + 1;
  if _buf = nil then
    Result := iSize
  else if _size < iSize then
    Result := -1
  else begin
    Move(PAnsiChar(StrUtf8)^, _buf^, iSize);
    Result := iSize - 1;
  end;
end;

exports
  TestFunction;

begin
end.
```

Comment: I compile the dll in Delphi 11.2 and calling from C++ builder 5 , I will try char* pointer instead as you said.

Comment: @mesutuk that is important information that should have been in your question up front

Comment: if I terminate the string with null in delphi     typedef char*(__stdcall *pfRes)(int,int);
   pfRes TestFuntion;  in c++ builder i can get the string but still having pointer error as I couldn't figure out how to pass the string into the pointer.

Comment: @mesutuk I've added code examples to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot , you are a star.